# Filtering Elements in XPath based on their descendants' text

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Suppose I have a table with the following rows,

```
...
<tr>
  <th title="Library of Quintessential Memes">LQM:</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th title="Library of Boring Books">LBB:</th>
</tr>
...
```

I would like to select all `<tr>` elements whose first `<th>` child's text starts with "L". How can I do this using XPath selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `starts-with` function:

```
//tr[starts-with(th[1],"L")]
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to select all `<tr>` elements who have a descendant `<a>` (not necessarily a direct descendant) whose text starts with "L"?